# Java Serial port string read [Determine string length]

Tags: java, string, serial-port

I am reading variable string from com port. Highest length of the string is 24. If I read string lower than that, for example it read 10 length string but still whenever I am measuring the length it always give 24. How to remove extra spaces if it is lower than highest length.

```
        serialPort.openPort();//Open serial port
        serialPort.setParams(9600, 8, 1, 0);//Set params.
        byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(24);//Read 10 bytes from serial port
        String str = new String(buffer);
        int t= str.length();
        System.out.println(t);
```

Comment: You should precise : what is the import/library you're using for serial communication. Also, how do you know that the lenght is less than 24? Because you see some trailing/leading special character? If yes, then could these characters be part of the normal output also?

Comment: It is likely that your extra characters are not padding, but rather part of another message.  Serial ports have no inherent  concept of boundaries - you have to deduce those from time (weak) or special delimiter characters, like a newline or null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `buffer` is 24 bytes long, that's how much data was received. Not 10. If you want ten bytes:

```
byte[] buffer = serialPort.readBytes(10);
```

Comment: Yes. I try this it works. However its variable sometimes port get 10 sometimes 15 highest it get 24. In that case what will be the solution

Comment: It depends. If you know the length you're expeting, use that length, if you don't, you have to treat the port as a byte stream and parse it to get what you need. There are no message boundaries in streams. Identifying messages is up to you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the trim() method to remove leading and trailing spaces.

```
str=str.trim();
```

Comment: The trim() method will not by itself remove the leading and trailing spaces; it returns a copy that has the leading and trailing spaces. Did you just do str.trim() or did you do str=str.trim()? trim() should remove all trailing spaces..

Comment: str=str.trim(); It always print 24 as readbytes(24) specifies.